# Backbone.js, Rails 3 and ActiveRecord Relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, backbone.js

Before I start, let me excuse myself for asking such a basic question, but I really didn't find any suitable information.

So, I have two ActiveRecord Models, Managers and Orders:

```
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible ...
    has_many :orders
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :manager
```

I have a backbone collection, which perfectly fetches managers. But what I don't get is how to get my manager's orders. Is there a solution for that or should I handle this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch a list of managers, with each manager having a list of their orders in JSON format, I highly recommend the rabl gem. It makes it very easy to set this up and if needed customize what's included in the JSON, whether you're using Backbone, KnockoutJS or something else on the front end.